# Numpy array into list

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array that looks like below:

```
x = ['11BIT' '4FUNMEDIA' 'ABCDATA' 'ABPL' 'ACAUTOGAZ' 'ADIUVO']
```

The output should be like this:

```
x = ['11BIT', '4FUNMEDIA', 'ABCDATA', 'ABPL', 'ACAUTOGAZ', 'ADIUVO']
```

I tried to use  x.tolist() but it didn't help. Basically I need a coma between values. Anyone could help ?

Thanks All

Comment: What does that even mean, 'I need a comma between values'?

Comment: Python uses a comma to separate values within any list-like object. The comma doesn't really exist in the array. I don't really see how you could have gotten your first result.

Comment: Perhaps it was unclear. I have a array that has 6 elements and I need to convert into list with 6 elements

Comment: What was wrong with `x = x.tolist()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"A comma between values" as in a string?

```
",".join(x)
```

if you want a true list:

```
x = list(x)
```

or

```
x = [i for i in x]
```

should do the trick

Comment: your numpy array doesn't look like any I've ever seen before -- is it a named index? Can you send a picture? Or a print out? I've never seen one w/ a " " delim